# Including multiple child layers in LINQ to SQL

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have a data model which has three layers as follows:

- Market Message
- MessageType598
- Metered Generation Information

The classes are as follows:

```
[Table("MarketMessage")]
    public partial class MarketMessage
    {
        public MarketMessage()
        {
            messageType300 = new HashSet<messageType300>();
            messageType300S = new HashSet<messageType300S>();
            messageType300W = new HashSet<messageType300W>();
            messageType305 = new HashSet<messageType305>();
            messageType310 = new HashSet<messageType310>();
            messageType310W = new HashSet<messageType310W>();
            messageType320 = new HashSet<messageType320>();
            messageType320W = new HashSet<messageType320W>();
            messageType332 = new HashSet<messageType332>();
            messageType332W = new HashSet<messageType332W>();

            messageType591 = new HashSet<messageType591>();
            messageType594 = new HashSet<messageType594>();
            messageType595 = new HashSet<messageType595>();
            messageType596 = new HashSet<messageType596>();
            messageType597 = new HashSet<messageType597>();
            messageType598 = new HashSet<messageType598>();
        }

        public int MarketMessageID { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(4)]
        public string messageType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string VersionNumber { get; set; }

        public DateTime MarketTimestamp { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string TxRefNbr { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Sender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        public string Recipient { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string alertFlag { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string fileName { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType300> messageType300 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType300S> messageType300S { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType300W> messageType300W { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType305> messageType305 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType310> messageType310 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType310W> messageType310W { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType320> messageType320 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType320W> messageType320W { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType332> messageType332 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType332W> messageType332W { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType591> messageType591 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType594> messageType594 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType595> messageType595 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType596> messageType596 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType597> messageType597 { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<messageType598> messageType598 { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class messageType598 
    {
        public int messageType598ID { get; set; }

        public int MarketMessageID { get; set; }

        public DateTime SettlementDate { get; set; }

        public int SettlementRunIndicator { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(9)]
        public string GenerationUnit { get; set; }
    }


    [Table("MeteredGenerationInformation")]
    public partial class MeteredGenerationInformation
    {
        [Key]
        public int MeteredGenerationInfoID { get; set; }

        public DateTime IntervalPeriodTimestamp { get; set; }

        public int SettlementInterval { get; set; }

        public decimal GenerationUnitMeteredGeneration { get; set; }

        public decimal LossAdjustedGenerationUnitMeteredGeneration { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType594ID { get; set; }

        public int? MessageType598ID { get; set; }
    }
```

I am attempting to join a list of all market messages received of type 598 including the metered generation information but I am unsure how to do this via LINQ to SQL. I have attempted the following:

```
var list598s = db.MarketMessage.Where(mm => mm.messageType == "598")
                .Include(mm => mm.messageType598)
                .ToList();
```

This includes the market messages including the 598 information but how can I include the metered generation information also in this list, I would also ideally like to refine the list based on a date field found within the messageType598 level

As a SQL query I would write the following:

```
select * from MarketMessage as a
inner join messageType598 as b on a.MarketMessageID = b.MarketMessageID
inner join MeteredGenerationInformation as c on b.messageType598ID = c.messageType598ID
where c.IntervalPeriodTimestamp between '1 aug 2016' and '31 aug 2016'
```

Comment: Why do you have all these different `messageTypexxx` classes? That looks like very poor normalization. What if you select "598" MarketMessages and `Include` messageType310? Does that even make sense?

Comment: Hi Gert, market message is the parent class these can be of different type of the message types each has a different structure, how could I improve the normalization?

Comment: I also figured that each of the message types would have their own controller so in this instance I would only be including the 598 messages

Comment: How to improve normalization? Well, have *one* `messageType` class/table having a property/field `messageTypeNumber` that contains one of the `xxx` values.

Comment: There is a parent class of Market Message, it is normalized according to a production schema that is already in place on a TPT basis